# why does wordpress template seem to negate html code?

Tags: php, wordpress

Ive been creating websites in html/css and by help of wordpress sometimes. Talking of wordpress templates there are some concepts which i do not grasp.
Wp templates are made of php files and have their own coding like instead of

```
<a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/minamaze/image/AJTFixPreisBanner.jpg"></a>
```

i have to write following to include an image:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/AJTFixPreisBanner.jpg"align="middle" />
```

why doesnt simple html code not work and why for example does following tweak of the wp template code not work for me(to center image) ?

```
<img align="middle" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/AJTFixPreisBanner.jpg" />
```

Obviously im not that familiar with wp templates codes as i would like to be , is there a comprehensive literature to gain this knowledge (the wordpress codex page is not comprehensive enough imo and at my level

Comment: To post formatted code, indent the code 4 spaces, or highlight it and use the `{}` editor toolbar button or `ctl-k` - this provides syntax highlighting and avoids issues like you had with the post misinterpreting HTML markup.

Comment: Remove that wpcontent and give the path from your theme directory. Like image/img png or <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/image/img.png

Comment: um, you set `align="center"` but then after the `src` attribute you re-set `align="middle"`

Comment: html works but using wp functions ensures that e.g. moving the site does not affect anything. only the site url has to be changed in the admin.

Comment: @chiliNUT  thx i corrected it

Comment: @latrellvie did that fix your issue or is still not centering correctly? Also IIRC `align` is deprecated and you should center it using css

Comment: @chiliNUT it was a typo my and unfortunatly it still didnt fix anything

Comment: actually html is working like if i add size="50%" to the image element image gets smaller accordingly .... but the align="middle" somehow still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Provided your containing element is wide enough and has the correct `display` attribute, the code below should work:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/AJTFixPreisBanner.jpg" style="text-align:center;" />
```

If that works, why not take it a step further and create a `center` CSS class?

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/AJTFixPreisBanner.jpg" class="center" />
```

Then add the following to your css file (most themes allow custom css in their settings)

```
.center {
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the URL of site is: http://www.example.com

When on the home page, you can certainly use this code simply:

```
<img src="/wp-content/minamaze/image/AJTFixPreisBanner.jpg">
```

The URL will translate to:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/minamaze/image/AJTFixPreisBanner.jpg
```

And it's okay.

But when you use this code in an inner page say `http://www.example.com/about/` then the URL of the image will translate to:

```
http://www.example.com/about/wp-content/minamaze/image/AJTFixPreisBanner.jpg
```

And it won't work this time because this URL is incorrect. That's why it's recomended to make use of functions like `bloginfo`, `site_url` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it; the challenge was caused by `align="middle"`.

```
<center>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/AJTFixPreisBanner.jpg" width="25%" margin="auto"/>
</center>
```